# no button component in qml/qt design mode

Tags: qt

I am transferring one of my Delphi project to QT

When I do GUI design, there is no button control in qml types

[image]

or I have to add button using code?

```
    Button {
        //...
    }
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: @Prince: This is not a Delphi question, and the tag is inappropriate. This is a question about QT. The fact the poster used to use another language doesn't make the old language tag relevant; there's no content relevant to Delphi here. I've removed the tag.

Comment: @KenWhite OP mentioned `Delphi Project` so I thought it calls for the tag to attract right people here who have tranferred Delphi project to QT. My bad!

Comment: Have you tried to add [`import QtQuick.Controls 1.1`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html) to the `qml` file? I suspect that UI designer proposes control palette according to import statements in `qml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add [import statement](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html) to `qml` file:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
```